# Smooth like totoro

Tags: smooth

I would like smooth mesh like totoro ears but I don't know how to smooth both the edges and the tip of the ears.

I have try but I can only bevel the base, do you have any advice?

[image]

I can't make the base and the tip together.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a reason for creating it apart from the head? And also for using so many edges?

Maybe begin with an 8 vertex cylinder:

[image]

Extrude up several times and scale down the radius of the extrusion:

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, add some edge loops so that it gives the desired shape:

[image]